# adding a column to a data frame in R based on the rank of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a reproducible example of my data. For the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Subject = c('John', 'John', 'John', 'John','Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Mary'),
                 SNR = c(-4,-4,0,4,0,4,4,8))
```

I would like to add a column 'rank' that provides a ranking for SNR by Subject, so that it would look like this:

```
Subject   SNR   Rank
John      -4    1
John      -4    1
John       0    2
John       4    3
Mary       0    1
Mary       4    2
Mary       4    2
Mary       8    3
```

I have tried using:

```
dfNew <- transform(df, Rank = ave(SNR, Subject, FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")))
```

But I get the following:

```
Subject   SNR   Rank
John      -4    1
John      -4    2
John       0    3
John       4    4
Mary       0    1
Mary       4    2
Mary       4    3
Mary       8    4
```

I have also tried using the different ties.method options, but none give me what I am looking for (i.e., ranking only from 1-3).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try with `dplyr::dense_rank`.   Or just use its code if you don't want to use a package; it's only two lines  of base R code.

Comment: `function(x) as.numeric(factor(x))` would work in your attempt. or just `factor(x)` since ave will coerce back to the type of `SNR` anyway

Comment: Thank you @rawr, that did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate` and `factor` in base R:

```
ag <- aggregate(SNR~Subject, df, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x)))
df$rank <- c(t(ag[,-1]))

  Subject SNR rank
1    John  -4    1
2    John  -4    1
3    John   0    2
4    John   4    3
5    Mary   0    1
6    Mary   4    2
7    Mary   4    2
8    Mary   8    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R method:

```
transform(df1, Rank = ave(SNR, Subject, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(TRUE, head(x, -1) != tail(x, -1)))))
```

gives:

```
  Subject SNR Rank
1    John  -4    1
2    John  -4    1
3    John   0    2
4    John   4    3
5    Mary   0    1
6    Mary   4    2
7    Mary   4    2
8    Mary   8    3
```

If your dataframe is not ordered yet, you should order it first with `df1 <- df1[order(df1$SNR),]` for this method to give the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

A bit dirty but it seems to work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Subject) %>% mutate(Rank = as.numeric(as.factor(SNR))) 

  Subject   SNR  Rank
   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    John    -4     1
2    John    -4     1
3    John     0     2
4    John     4     3
5    Mary     0     1
6    Mary     4     2
7    Mary     4     2
8    Mary     8     3
```

Comment: Not my vote, but I am guessing it's because you don't really need to load a  package to add a column.

Comment: Well you have to load dplyr if you don't use it regularly, I reckon the down vote(not by me) was due to as.numeric(as.factor())..but still that's a bit pedantic

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>%
     arrange(Subject, SNR) %>%
     group_by(Subject) %>%
     mutate(rank=dense_rank(SNR))
```

of course credit to @rich-scriven for mentioning `dense_rank()`